# How to make subcategory for custom post and and display?

Tags: categories

I've created a custom post with categories like books, foods, and make some sub-categories like in foods cat, pizza, fastfood. But when I display them in my side bar, it's showing same as sub category. Just like:

> .books
>
> .foods
>
> .pizza
>
> .fastfood

I want them to display like this:

> .books
>
> .foods
>
> -pizza
>
> -fastfood

Here is my code of functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'products_register');

function products_register() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('products', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Products Item', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'products item'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New products Item'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit products Item'),
        'new_item' => __('New products Item'),
        'view_item' => __('View products Item'),
        'search_items' => __('Search products'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        //'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/article16.png',
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
    ); 

    register_post_type( 'products' , $args );

    register_taxonomy("productcategory", array("products"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Product Category", "singular_label" => "Product Category", "rewrite" => true));

}
```

Here is my code to display the category on my sidebar:

```
<?php

$taxonomy = 'productcategory';
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy); // Get all terms of a taxonomy

if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Revisit the [`register_taxonomy`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) codex article. You have some issues in your  registration - mainly the labels should be inside a `labels` array.

Comment: can you show me code, sorry i am new in PHP . and also edit my Question

Answer (score 1):

Use [wp_list_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories). It automatically builds a hierarchical list, and links to them. This should do everything you want!

Comment: Eric Holmes, this is not post category, this is custom post category.

Comment: Look at the documentation. You can specify `taxonomy`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$show_count = 0; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical = 1; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$taxonomy = 'productcategory';
$title = '';
$args = array(
  'orderby' => $orderby,
  'show_count' => $show_count,
  'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
  'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
  'title_li' => $title
);
<ul>
<?php
    wp_list_categories($args);
?>
</ul>
```

I've tried this and it is working fine.
I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WordPress function [wp_list_categories($args)](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/#parameters) to create what you are looking for.

When you register your taxonomy, you also need to set `hierarchical` to `true` to be able to nest your Custom Post Type categories.

After, you can just create a function like this one (With basics $args) :

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'taxonomy' => 'productcategory',
    'hide_empty' => false
);

wp_list_categories($args);

?>
```

Not that we are using the `'taxonomy' => 'productcategory',` parameter to tell the function to look on the taxonomy itself.

Your HTML output will looks like this.

```
<ul>    
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-18"><a href="http://wordpress.local/productcategory/books/" >Books</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-19"><a href="http://wordpress.local/productcategory/foods/" >Foods</a>
        <ul class='children'>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-21"><a href="http://wordpress.local/productcategory/fastfood/" >Fastfood</a></li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-20"><a href="http://wordpress.local/productcategory/pizza/" >Pizza</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The way that you initaly developped this is good to get a list. But it won't display it as hierarchical elements.

After, you will just need to play arround with CSS to add `padding` on `.children` class.

[image: HTML Output of the code]

Hope it help.